# Stream video from web camera using UWP app in C#

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, webcam

I am trying to stream video from my webcam (audio and video) from .NET UWP IOT application.

I tried this WebCamApp sample from https://github.com/ms-iot/samples and it works perfectly. Now I would like to play with streaming that video to another PC/device. I am open to your suggestions on how to approach this. In past I was dealing with RTSP, but not on this platform. So far I saw that limitation is the .NET Core.

Are there any libraries for this? Or should i write something from scratch? What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution, but what you're looking for is real time streaming. and I recommend using WebRTC.
WebRTC is a project built by google to support real time communication, you can play around with the sample from this website:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/

I found also this port for UWP, applications. But I'm not sure if it works with IOT:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebRTC/